# Show loading icon while the page is getting loaded from server side, in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have a mvc application. The view gets loaded with data from server side. While the page is loading, there is a delay due to lot of data. Until the page gets rendered and fully loaded in the browser i need to show a loading icon to the user.
I have done this for client side loaded pages, through jquery and knockout. But for server side loaded pages i m not able to find anything.
I tried adding a div to the view and then used the below code in my .cshtml file

```
 Response.Write("<Script>document.getElementById('progressdivmaster').style.display = 'block';</script>");
```

To refer the div and display.I know this is very stupid, as the page is not rendered by then and the code returns me an error saying "getelementid is null".

Is it possible to show a loading icon before the page gets rendered? If yes then someone please tell me. :(

Comment: When you need to fetch a lot of data, you should display the page first and show a loading icon before triggering the fetching of any data. You can then trigger the data fetching by an Ajax post request, receive the data, remove the loading icon, set the received data as ViewModel and then let knockout do its job. I usually do so for nearly all scenarios.

Comment: Frankly speaking i love knockout! but this page is already coded by someone else. And i cant afford to recode it back to implement client side loading. The approach you told, i have implement on other pages,but for this page i need some different approach.